# Basic query related to the type of the value going to be returned from readFileSync method?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

what will be the **output** of the following ?

```
const fs = require('fs');

var originalNote = {
  body: 'some body me1',
  title: 'some title'
};

var originalNoteString = JSON.stringify(originalNote);
fs.writeFileSync('notes.json', originalNoteString);
var noteString = fs.readFileSync('notes.json');
console.log(typeof noteString);
var note = JSON.parse(noteString);
console.log(typeof note);
```

Comment: Why don't you just run the code?!

Comment: The output is:
object 
object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read file sync:

`Returns: <string> | <Buffer>`

Specify 'utf8' as second parameter to get a string.  If no encoding is specified, then the raw buffer is returned.

```
var noteString = fs.readFileSync('notes.json', 'utf8');

console.log(typeof noteString);
```

This is a string, typeof would be 'string' or 'buffer'

```
console.log(typeof note);
```

This would depend on JSON value of string, This assuming the string was parsable JSON.  In your case 'object'
.

```js
var aString = '{"foo":"a string"}'
console.log(typeof aString);
var parsed = JSON.parse(aString);
console.log(typeof parsed);
```

Comment: but console.log('typeof noteString') is showing object as its type

Comment: Specify 'utf8' as the second parameter or you might get a Buffer instead of a string.  Updated answer.

Comment: But the output of console.log('typeof originalNoteString'); is string not object then how come typeof noteString is object ??

Comment: fs returns a buffer unless you specify encoding.

Comment: when utf-8 is added then output changed to string in console.log('typeof noteString');  earlier it was showing as object. What is the role of utf-8 in this ?

Comment: fs does not know the encoding of the saved file. Is it binary, unicode, ascii, etc. If you do not indicate this it returns a generic byte buffer.  The buffer can then convert to a variety of encodings.